# Opening balance and closing balance for a non-working date

Tags: mysql

Need a help on how to get opening balances and closing balances of a non-working date in my transaction table in my database.

**transaction table**

```
+------------------+----------+-----------+
| id | trans_date  | debit    | credit    |
+----+-------------+----------+-----------+
|  1 |  2016-05-09 |  200.00  |    0.00   |
|  2 |  2016-05-11 |    0.00  |    50.00  | 
+---------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Want a result like below. You will realize there were no transaction on "2016-05-10" but the result shows both opening balance and closing balance. Thanks

```
+-------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| trans_date  | open_bal     | debit     | credit    |closing_bal |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|  2016-05-09 |         0.00 |   200.00  |    0.00   | 200.00     |
|  2016-05-10 |       200.00 |     0.00  |    0.00   | 200.00     |
|  2016-05-11 |       200.00 |     0.00  |   50.00   | 150.00     |
+-------------+-------------+--------------+------------+---------+
```

I tried this but "2016-05-10" does not show in the result.

```
SELECT trans_date,open_balance
FROM(SELECT s.gen_id, s.trans_id, s.trans_date,
s.narations, s.account_code,
s.op_balance as open_balance,
s.debit, s.credit, s.closing_balance
from ( select t.gen_id, t.trans_id,
t.narations, t.account_code,
t.trans_date, t.credit, t.debit,
@tot_debit := if(@prev_client = t.account_code, @tot_debit + t.debit,t.debit) as tot_cred,
@tot_credit := if(@prev_client = t.account_code,@tot_credit + t.credit,t.credit) as tot_deb,
@cur_bal := if(@prev_client = t.account_code, @tot_debit - @tot_credit,t.debit-t.credit) as closing_balance,
(@cur_bal + t.credit) - t.debit as op_balance, @prev_client := t.account_code
from (select * from journal WHERE account_code = 41003
GROUP BY trans_date order by trans_date,account_code,trans_id)t, (select @prev_client:=0,@cur_bal:=0,@tot_debit:=0,@tot_credit:= 0,@open_balance:=0)r )s) g where trans_date <= '2016-05-11'
```

Comment: You're welcome. At least try something before you ask.

Comment: Just handle the logic of missing dates in your application level code

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to select list of dates in MySQL.

```sql
SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE() , INTERVAL -(a.n + 10 * b.n + 100 * c.n) DAY) AS `date`
FROM (SELECT 1 AS n UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) AS a
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS n UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) AS b
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS n UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) AS c
```

If you want to include in result dates not presented at table `transactions`, it can be done with `LEFT JOIN`

```sql
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE() , INTERVAL -(a.n + 10 * b.n + 100 * c.n) DAY) AS `date`
    FROM (SELECT 1 AS n UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) AS a
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS n UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) AS b
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS n UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) AS c
  ) AS dates
  LEFT JOIN transactions ON trans_date = dates.date
```

Note, that this will select dates from current for 999 past days. If you want more days ago, another `CROSS JOIN` can be added and 9 999 days will be returned.